# AsyncTask and CursorLoader [Android]

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

My `AsyncTask` for fetching data is a long one, and at the same time, in the midst of constructing my `recyclerview` I wanted to check if a `cursorloader` was able to query from my content provider correctly.

Bear with me here, I used Loader Callbacks `interface` and `onLoadFinished` to get results. Since the `asynctask` is still running, the loader still calls the content provider as it gets updated until `asynctask` ends. I would except that since `onLoadFinished` primarily deals with filling in the contents of an `adapter` with cursor data that I shouldn't worry that it prints out log statements simultaneously as the `asynctask` continues to run, but I wanted to confirm.

I do intend to eventually move this `asynctask` into an `intentservice` that only gets called via `broadcast`.

Comment: I, to be honest do not really understand what you want. You want to get the results later right?

Comment: Also, please add some code you tried. I cannot help If I barely understand the question and two, if I do not see anything tried.

Comment: apologies, I wrote the question in a haste before heading to sleep while thinking about it myself. I have code, but long story short, the asynctask is running and inserting into my content provider while the cursor loader keeps getting refreshed as new data flows in until asynctask is done. As this would happen only when the program first boots up, would it eventually affect my UI and Recycler View loading down the line while I'm implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(URL_LOADER, null, HomeFragment.this);` to restart the loader on you AsyncTask onPostExecute method. You need to init the Loader first on you `onCreate()` method.

This way, the loader will refresh with the same projection it had when you started it and it will fetch the results of the AsyncTask operations from DB.

Comment: Seems like the right approach, but I might need to find a way to call the LoaderManager from my asynctask, which is in a separate file.

you made a good guess without me giving code that my fragment implement Callback methods for Loading. I made the post like seconds before I went to sleep to think about it.

Comment: @kthieu you can use EventBus, Otto or any other event oriented library for that purpouse.